# How to fix "param is missing or the value is empty: team"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to update an existing team name. The user goes to the website, enters what they want it to be in a text box and clicks 'Enter' to submit the change. However, I'm getting a params error, even though I believe I'm sending in the id.

I've searched the internet, tried pry, deleted/altered/and updated everything I can think of, but no luck. I know this is programming 101, but I'm at a complete wall.

I've included (what I hope is) the pertinent coding, starting with the controller:

```
  def update
    #binding.pry
    team = Team.find(params[:id])
    team.update!(team_params)
          ...........
  private
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:team_name)
  end
```

*****html:

```
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Update Team Name</h1>
    <br>
      <%= form_for :team, url: team_path, method: :patch do |team| %>
      <input class="text_field" value="<%= @team.name %>" team.text_field :team_name, required: true %>
    <br>

    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Changes" class="btn btn-success" />
    </p>
  </div>
```

I expected for the user to type what they want the team name to be updated to, and it would stick. However, I get the following error message:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in TeamsController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: team
Extracted source (around line #99):

Comment: Try printing something to see if its even getting in the update function, maybe check your logs to see what request is being sent over to the back

Answer (score 1):

`team_path` neads an `id` to work

```
<%= form_for :team, url: team_path(@team.id), method: :patch do |team| %>
```

You should however be good with this also

```
<%= form_for @team, method: :patch do |team| %>
```

or even

```
<%= form_for @team do |team| %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!